# Does the Bolt protocol work with Traefik?

Tags: neo4j, proxy, kubernetes, load-balancing, traefik

Does the bolt protocol which is used by Neo4j works with Traefik?

TCP is not supported yet by Traefik, but according to the Traefik documention, it supports WebSocket(which operates over a TCP connection), and this confuses me!

Is it possible to run Neo4j databases behind Traeffik and access them using something like `bolt://myhost/path/that/traefik/routes/to/my/db`?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be up to each client library, and from what I can see it looks like only a few browser-based clients actually use the WebSocket mode. So overall, probably no, pending 2.0 coming out.